# Android fragments : I use the xml to define hint or text : when I want to dynamically update text or hint, the new text overlaps

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, textview, android-edittext

Do fragment need a very precise way of handling the texts that are set in the xml of the fragment ?

I had two times very similar problems : text written in xml cannot be updated properly.

Here is my first fragment. I previously had a foolish text written in the xml for the textview 'msg2ndfragment'. The issue I had was that during the onViewCreated, the text sent by the new Activity to the text would overlap the foolish text written in the Xml.
So I removed the foolish text, and now it is fine. (I could update thee text three times in a row it would work as long as the text was not initially defined in the xml),

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

//Passer par new instance pour créé le fragment en lui donnant le nom à afficher
companion object {
    fun newInstance(title: String?): SecondFragment {
        val fragmentSecond = SecondFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(MainActivity.MESSAGE_SECOND_ACTIVITE, title)
        fragmentSecond.arguments = args
        return fragmentSecond
    }
}

private lateinit var viewModel: SecondViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false)
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SecondViewModel::class.java)

    val message = arguments!!.getString(MainActivity.MESSAGE_SECOND_ACTIVITE, "")


    val aries = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.msg2ndfragment);
    aries?.text = message
}


}
```

But now, I have a very similar issue: in a different fragment in another activity I have an editText with a hint. I want to make the hint disappear. Same issue : if the hint is written in the Xml : any text written by the user will only overlap the old text. If I initially define the hint dynamically, the hint disappears when the user starts writing.

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    val aries = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGo2ndActivity);
    aries?.setOnClickListener { onGoSecondFragmentClick(it) }
    Log.d("p1", "p1");
    //Faire disparaitre le int au touch car cela ne se fait pas automatiquement
    val edTxtTo2nd = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edt2ndActEditText)
    edTxtTo2nd?.hint =  "a"
    Log.d("pouf", "pouf");

    /*val edTxtTo2nd = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edt2ndActEditText)
    edTxtTo2nd?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
        edTxtTo2nd?.setHint("")
    }) */
}


private var listener: onMvmtClickListener? = null

public interface onMvmtClickListener {
    fun onNextActivityClick(name1: String)
}

// Store the listener (activity) that will have events fired once the fragment is attached
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is onMvmtClickListener) {
        listener = context as onMvmtClickListener
    } else {
        throw ClassCastException(
            "$context must implement nMvmtClickListener"
        )
    }
}

fun onGoSecondFragmentClick(v: View?) {
    val nom = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edt2ndActEditText);
    listener?.onNextActivityClick(nom?.text.toString())
}


}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGo2ndActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/go_to_2nd_act"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edt2ndActEditText"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="111dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt2ndActEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnGo2ndActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/message"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="95dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit : here are the main_activity kotelin and xml

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainFragment.onMvmtClickListener  {
companion object{
    const val MESSAGE_SECOND_ACTIVITE = "Message.s

econd.activite"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow()
        }
    }

    override fun onNextActivityClick(name1: String) {
        var intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_SECOND_ACTIVITE, name1)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id

/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Using this workaround to define any text or hint feels wrong to me. How can I define them in the Xml of the fragment without having this overlap issue ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It sounds like you're ending up with multiple, overlapping `Fragment` instances. Probably the quickest way to check that is to set a temporary, solid background color on the root `View` in the `main_fragment` layout. If you can't see it anymore, that's the problem. In any case, it would help to see the layout that `MainFragment` is loaded into, and any code that you're using to load it.

Comment: Yeah, you're ending up with two `Fragment` instances, one atop the other. A `<fragment>` element is not just a placeholder. It causes a `Fragment` instance to be loaded automatically when the layout is set. The one you're creating in code is being stuck into that one, and you're seeing its `EditText` and the hint behind the one you're typing in. If you want to handle your `Fragment` programmatically, then change that to a `<FrameLayout>`, and remove the `android:name` attribute. Otherwise, you can remove the code you have for that in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed,  I removed *if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow()
in the activity and it works.

thank you very much !